# Develop a chrome extension to test websites for checking browser compatibility?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to develop a chrome extension which can simulator all browsers (IE 6-9 firefox, safari) so when I am developing a website I can switch views to see how my website will look in different browser according to the selection.

I am new to extension development. I have develop the extension in  which I can do basic operation. like get page URL reload page. insert the style in Page  etc. But how to do browser  simulator?

Any Idea or suggestion will really help.

**EDIT:**
Waat to develop some thing simillar to
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab-classic/miedgcmlgpmdagojnnbemlkgidepfjfi

Comment: You're trying to re-write IE6 in Chrome? Don't do that.

Comment: I think you need a computer that already has Trident. I'd really like to see your implementation if you make it work on a non-Windows machine.

Comment: @SLaks I am not trying to re-write IE6 i just want to make an instance of IE in a iframe or somting like that...

Comment: see the added link... I want to develop some thing simillar to that

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as extensions are part of the Chrome itself, they can not be used to simulate other browsers' engines.

The best thing you can do is to develop an extension which will automatically integrate with and poll some external service which supports testing against different browser brands and versions, such as:

- [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org);
- [Adobe's browser lab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/);

Whereas it's feasible to write an NPAPI plugin encapsulating IE COM component (though it's a lot of work and is likely to face some nuances) and utilize it through the extension, there are no analogous means for FireFox or Opera. BTW, if you mean you need not only rendering (that can be perfectly checked by screenshots) but dynamic interaction with user, then the task is even more difficult. In this case, again, you can do it only by means of a custom external service running target browsers, which are controlled remotely by your extension. This is doable, but requires apparently much more work than a simple extension. In fact you need to develop a specific service first.

Comment: i just dont want the screen shot of the website.. i need the complete rendring. so i can use chrome developer tool to fix bugs in IE :)

Comment: @Champ, yes, I know, this is why I wrote this is hardly possible just within an extension. I'm adding more info in the answer.

Comment: ok... got you point.but why its not possible to create instance( or to use the rending engine ) of the browsers already present in the local machine.

Comment: @Champ, This will be the same service just running on your local PC. Of course you can do that.